# Can I draw the same DisplayObject multiple times?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a loop that runs and adds a `TextField` from an array to a `Sprite`, and draws that `Sprite` to a `BitmapData` object. When I reference a previously drawn `TextField`, nothing is drawn to the `BitmapData`.

```
public class Pocket extends Sprite
{
    public var inventory:Array = [textField1, textField2, textField3]; //array of TextFields, populated by another class
    public var order:Array = [0,1,2,1]; //array of ints indicating the order of which items in "inventory" should be displayed (the error lies when an element is repeated - in this case, 1

    public function getItem(index:int):Array
    {
        var bitmaps:Array = new Array();

        for(var i:int = 0; i < order.length; i++)
        {
            var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(32, 32);

            var background:Sprite = new Sprite();
            background.graphics.beginFill();
            background.graphics.drawRect(0,0,32,32);
            background.graphics.endFill();
            bitmapData.draw(background); //this always executes as expected

            var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
            sprite.addChild(inventory[order[i]]);

            bitmapData.draw(sprite);

            var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData);
            bitmaps.push(bitmap);

            sprite.removeChild(inventory[order[i]]);
        }
        return bitmaps;
    }
}
```

When the last element in `order` is called (1), the resulting Bitmap does not contain a textfield.

[image: Example]

When the loop runs the first time, adding the `TextField` `inventory[0]` to a `Sprite`, the `Sprite` is drawn as expected. The second box is drawn, using `inventory[1]`. However, when I run the same code trying to draw `inventory[1]` a second time, nothing happens. The same would happen if I try to draw `inventory[0]`, but if I use a `TextField` that has yet to be added to a `Sprite` (ex. `inventory[2]`, should one exist), it draws as expected.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you add the `DisplayObject` to a `Sprite` first? Why not draw it directly? It's not really clear to me what the problem is from your code. Could you please elaborate on what you mean by "previously drawn"?  Could you please extend your code so that it includes a part where you do not get the intended result? thank you.

Comment: Left out some important information (my bad). Added an example along with some elaboration.

Comment: If you draw any of the Textfields again, it will have no visible effect, because they are drawn in the same place.

Comment: Maybe you should add more code to show the the part where something is getting redrawn.

Comment: @null Each TextField is added to a Sprite, the Sprite is drawn to a BitmapData object, and a Bitmap is created. I'm adding that Bitmap to the stage. The position of the TextField shouldn't matter.

Comment: What @SunilD. suggests sounds like a good idea. If you can, simply post all the code you have.

Comment: I've added the entire class to the original post. Hope this helps! Thanks for bearing with me

Comment: How come your `getItem` does not use `index` parameter at all? It's possible that you are expecting youtr method to return different bitmap arrays, but instead you get one and only, and then you query something weird outside, and get a blank bitmap. (On a side note, you'd better create black background by `var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(32, 32, false, 0x000000);` instead of overdrawing a white (default color) bitmap with a black sprite.)

Comment: Also, it might be better if you don't play with `addChild()/removeChild()` outside of visible display list, it's quite possible that your `textfield1`'s coordinates and/or cached bitmap is cleared once you add and then remove it from a display object that was never rendered. Instead, draw the `TextField` objects themselves.